# Cross compiling: gcc with sysroot still can't find files

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile on my PC for ARMv6 device. normal programs compiles fine, but now I need some native hardware libs to be linked to program. 
So I copied the desired shared libs from the device (*device:/opt/vc* into */path/to/cross-compiler/sysroot/opt/vc*)
But gcc complains about header files/libs doesn't exist. I guess it's looking for them in the local root path, and not cross-compiler's sysroot.

So the new files are under:

```
ls $(cross-compiler)/sysroot/opt/vc
./include
./lib
```

Here's *$(cross-compiler)-gcc -v* result:

```
Configured with:
--with-sysroot=$(cross-compiler)/sysroot
blah blah ...
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/vc/include"
```

I also used *--sysroot* flag manually to point to the path, but still doesn't work
How can I make it work ?